# With Flask or Quart NameError: global name 'g' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, quart

I got a problem when I tried to test a flask app that I can not access the `g` variable.

The api which is gonna tested looks like this:

```
user = query_object.get(g.user_id)   # here the exception raises
```

When I run the test, it raises:

```
NameError: global name 'g' is not defined
```

Answer (score 11):

What are your imports? You should try and add

```
from flask import g
```

Or, if you're using Quart

```
from quart import g
```